# He solicitado que mi cuenta se elimine y está aumentando el conteo del tiempo que falta para eliminarse

Tags: soporte, eliminación-de-usuarios

Ayer realicé el procedimiento para eliminar mi cuenta, el sistema me mandó un e-mail indicándome que por mi reputación y/o votos se requería de la aprobación final de un *developer*. Sin embargo cuando entro aparece lo siguiente en mi perfil:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
>
> Este cuenta se programó para eliminarse **el hace 4 minutos**. Para cancelar la eliminación, haz click aquí

Como pueden observar el tiempo de 24 horas ya se superó y ahora el conteo no se está reduciendo sino aumentando; ¿será que deba esperar más para que mi perfil sea eliminado?

Comment: Alpha, las pocas veces que he visto ese anuncio, en efecto el número iba disminuyendo, no aumentando. Lo investigarémos. Si te apetece explicarlo, ¿Por qué quieres eliminar la cuenta? Podemos comentarlo en privado, si lo deseas. Un saludo

Comment: Nada, el proceso ya se ha realizado. Parece ser que el proceso estaba aumentando en tiempo porque estaba en la cola de tareas de los comunity manager con tales privilegios. Una pena que el usuario se haya ido. Espero que algún dia vuelva a aportar. Al menos sus publicaciones se mantienen.

Comment: Una auténtica lástima que hayas decidido dejarnos. Cualquier problema que hayas tenido podríamos haberlo comentado. Un saludo y espero que decidas volver algún día

Comment: nos vemos Alpha/anonimo, que la fuerza os acompañe. Gracias por haber aportado en la comunidad

Comment: ¿Se mantienen los votos que hizo? Al leer las distintas explicaciones en los meta de SE no me queda claro.

Comment: @Shaz tendría que encontrar la fuente, pero me parece recordar que los votos de más de 6(?) meses se mantienen, pero los de menos se pierden... si encuentro donde leí eso, lo compartiré por aquí.

Comment: Parece ser que este usuario volvió, curiosamente tiene los mismos «conocimientos» que el perfil anterior: https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/128299/aprendiz